# Execute route if only the local Angular App calls it true the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a few API routes that only the app itself (`controller.js`) should have access to. Is there a way to use an IP address (possibly insecure because of spoofing) to create a restriction of who uses this part of the api?

**Server size (server.js)**

```
app.get("/api/specs",function(req,res){
    // Only the app should have access to it, not external entities
    res.json({used:getUsed()});
});
```

**Client side (controller.js)**

```
$http.get('/api/specs').success(function(specs,code){
    console.log(specs);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your browser doesn't allow you to make Cross-site HTTP requests because are subject of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

**Note:**

> In particular, this meant that a web application using XMLHttpRequest
>   could only make HTTP requests to the domain it was loaded from, and
>   not to other domains.

Which it means in your case that only the js in the same domain of your api can have access to them.

**What if I want to extend the use of the API to other domains?**

Well in this case you have to setup in your backend api the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

*Some eg:*

```
// Cross-site HTTP requests from http://siteA.com
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com

// Cross-site HTTP requests from all
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

If you want to debug this behaviour you can just open firebug and check in networks the headers of your requests.

**References:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: You might be misunderstanding what he asks about.

Comment: mmm @suish maybe you right I noticed now the part of the controller; but the part of the IP suggested me that was something related to the domains. how would you reformulate his question?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that using a GET parameter is the easiest way.

Node.js(express)

```
app.get("/api/specs",function(req,res){
  var queryParam = url.parse(req.url,true).query
  if(queryParam.whois == "yourUniqueName"){
    res.send("okay");
  }else{
    res.status(404);
    res.send("NG");
  }
});
```

angular

```
$http.get("/api/specs", {
    params: { whois: "yourUniqueName" }
});
```

define names something unique for each APIs.
and set the server returns response only when a client sends correct name.

server returns 404 except you pass `yourUniqueName` as query parameter `whois`.

```
/api/specs?whois=yourUniqueName
okay
```

.

```
/api/specs?whois=otherName
/api/specs?otherParam=something
/api/specs
NG
```